# Cual es la forma correcta de cast un clase en java

Tags: java, conversión-de-tipos, cast, casting

```
    private void Guardar(){
    Soldado soldados = new Soldado(Integer.parseInt(txtCodigo.getText()),txtNombre.getText(),txtApellido.getText(),
            txtGraduacion.getText(),((Clases.Compania)cbmCompañia.getSelectedItem()),(Clases.Cuerpo)cbmCuerpo.getSelectedItem());

    ListaSoldado.add(soldados);
    Mostrar();

    }

como se convierten de la manera correcta, ya que aunque caste el valor fuera el error permanece?

[![al momento de guardar lanza un error referente a los datos ingresados aparece como  si no se hubieran convertido bien][2]][2]

También intenté:

    private void Guardar(){ 
    Clases.Compania co= (Compania)cbmCompañia.getSelectedItem(); 
    Soldado soldados = new Soldado(Integer.parseInt(txtCodigo.getText()), txtNombre.getText(), txtApellido.getText(), txtGraduacion.getText(), co, (Clases.Cuerpo) cbmCuerpo.getSelectedItem()); 
    ListaSoldado.add(soldados); Mostrar(); 
    }


  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2O2vL.png

public class Compania {
    private int codigo;
    private String actividadPricipal;


    private ArrayList<Soldado>soldado;
    private Cuartel cuarte;

    public Compania(int codigo, String actividadPricipal,Cuartel cuarte) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.actividadPricipal = actividadPricipal;
        this.cuarte = cuarte;
    }
    public Compania(){

    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getActividadPricipal() {
        return actividadPricipal;
    }

    public void setActividadPricipal(String actividadPricipal) {
        this.actividadPricipal = actividadPricipal;
    }

    public ArrayList<Soldado> getSoldado() {
        return soldado;
    }

    public void setSoldado(ArrayList<Soldado> soldado) {
        this.soldado = soldado;
    }

    public Cuartel getCuarte() {
        return cuarte;
    }

    public void setCuarte(Cuartel cuarte) {
        this.cuarte = cuarte;
    }

     @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ""  + codigo +"-"+actividadPricipal ;
    }
}

 private int codigo;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellido;
    private String graduacion;
    private Compania compania;
    private Cuerpo cuerpo;


    public Soldado(int codigo, String nombre, String apellido, String graduacion, Compania compania, Cuerpo cuerpo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.graduacion = graduacion;
        this.compania = compania;
        this.apellido= apellido;
        this.cuerpo= cuerpo;

    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getGraduacion() {
        return graduacion;
    }

    public void setGraduacion(String graduacion) {
        this.graduacion = graduacion;
    }

    public Compania getCompania() {
        return compania;
    }

    public void setCompania(Compania compania) {
        this.compania = compania;
    }

    public String getApellido() {
        return apellido;
    }

    public void setApellido(String apellido) {
        this.apellido = apellido;
    }

    public Cuerpo getCuerpo() {
        return cuerpo;
    }

    public void setCuerpo(Cuerpo cuerpo) {
        this.cuerpo = cuerpo;
    }





}
```

aqui se encuentra tanto la clase compania, como la clase soldado que donde quiero guarda esa definición, en la vista trato de llamar compania en un LinkedList que esta dentro del jcombobox para guardar la definicion, en el objeto soldado que intento crear

aqui se encuentra tanto la clase compania, como la clase soldado que donde quiero guarda esa definición, en la vista trato de llamar compania en un LinkedList que esta dentro del jcombobox para guardar la definicion, en el objeto soldado que intento crear

Comment: eso ocurre al momento de guardar

Comment: Sugerencia: el código se comparte como texto, no como imagen. Lo pones difícil a quien te lee desde un móvil o pueda tener algún grado de discapacidad.

Comment: Sobre tu problema, no hay nada que le diga al compilador cómo debería transformar un String en una instancia de tu clase Compania. ¿Cómo debería mapear el String para que pase a tener los atributos y métodos de la clase Compania? No te suena más instanciar Compania y asignarle a la nueva instancia, el valor correspondiente a partir del String?

Comment: ya lo intente pero sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Qué intentaste para instanciar Compania asignando el valor del String? Por favor, inclúyelo en tu pregunta.

Comment: intente hacer esto   private void Guardar(){
    Clases.Compania co= (Compania)cbmCompañia.getSelectedItem();    
    Soldado soldados = new Soldado(Integer.parseInt(txtCodigo.getText()),txtNombre.getText(),txtApellido.getText(),
            txtGraduacion.getText(),co,(Clases.Cuerpo)cbmCuerpo.getSelectedItem());
    
    ListaSoldado.add(soldados);
    Mostrar();
    
       
    }

Comment: Lo único diferente en el código es que intentas hacer el cast que no es posible, por fuera de la otra instrucción. Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade la definición de la clase Compania.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo defines correctamente no es necesario el cast:

```
JComboBox<Clases.Compania> cbmCompania = new JComboBox<Clases.Compania>();
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Después de la aceptada observación, puede realizar el proceso de guardar el objeto con éxito, tras editar el tipo de parámetro a recibir